# Converting MGA coordinates for Google Earth?

Tags: coordinate-system, google-earth, australia

I am new to looking up coordinates, etc.

However, I have some coordinates that I want to look for, but they are in MGA.

I am wanting to look up these coordinates on Google Earth and then try and export them to my vms.

From what I can discover Google Earth does not like these MGA coordinates and I have zero know how on trying to convert them to a readable coordinate to allow me to do the above.

Is anyone able to help?

Comment: Here's a handy online tool: https://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=4326&t_srs=3308

Hopefully you have some idea about your MGA zone, but as long as you've got that info you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that these coordinates are from Australia.

MGA is the Map Grid of Australia.

"Map Grid of Australia" is mentioned in [three previous Q&As here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Map%20Grid%20of%20Australia%22), "MGA" is mentioned in [30 other questions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=mga%20is%3Aquestion), and [NSW Government Spatial Services](http://spatialservices.finance.nsw.gov.au/surveying/geodesy/projections) refers to it as:

```
The official coordinate projection for use with the Geocentric Datum of Australia 1994 (GDA94).

Projection: Transverse Mercator
Zone Width: 6 degrees
Longitude of Origin:    Central Meridian of each zone
Latitude of Origin: Equator (zero degrees)
False Easting:  500 000
False Northing: 10 000 000
Central Scale Factor:   0.9996
Units:  Metre
Ellipsoid:  GRS80
More Information:   Go to [ICSM][3] website.
```

The software that I use to convert from it to WGS 84 Web Mercator which Google uses as its coordinate system is ArcGIS Desktop.

Answer (score 0):

For individual coordinates there is this online tool: https://tool-online.com/en/coordinate-converter.php

Select Australia and choose the appropriate grid zone and datum,
picking the wrong datum gives an error of 300 meters.